# htm5 download attribute not working

Tags: html, download

when i'm downloading a file with the new html5 download attribute in it the filename is not overwritten by the download value...

suppose i have a download link like this

```
<a href="./file.jpg" download>link</a>
```

now i want to overwrite the original name of the file so i guess i'll have to do this

```
<a href="./file.jpg" download="newname.jpg">link</a>
```

but its not working the file keeps downloading with its original name...
how to resolve the problem????
i'm using google chrome with ubuntu wily

Comment: why do you have./ ?

Comment: In which browsers have you tested it?

Comment: it's working fine in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the file called "file.jpg" to the same directory and changing your code to

`<a href="file.jpg" download>link</a>` or change your code to `<a href="../file.jpg" download>link</a>`.

Answer (score -2):

This is a complete, working prompt with download button which provides a specific name. Works in Chrome, FireFox, and Edge.

```
<h3 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Get the TAAS Global Strategy FactSheets </span> <a class="fasc-button fasc-size-medium fasc-type-glossy fasc-rounded-medium" style="background-color: #494844; color: #ffffff;" href="https://taastrategies.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/TAAS-FactSheets.pdf" download="TAAS-FactSheets.pdf" data-fasc-style="background-color:#494844;color:#ffffff;">Free Download</a></h3>
```